# Store multiple checkbox values in database table Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

So far, I know I need to store the checkbox values in an array like so:

```
<input name="thinking_traps[]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input name="thinking_traps[]" type="checkbox" value="2">
<input name="thinking_traps[]" type="checkbox" value="3">
```

But I'm not sure how to correctly pass these values to the controller and add them to the migration table? Will each value be added as a separate column in the database?

Here I've tried adding adding them like any other input:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'thought_entry' => 'required'
        ]);



        $entry = new ThoughtJournal;
        $entry->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $entry['entry_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i');
        $entry->thought_entry = $request->input('thought_entry');
        $entry->emotions = $request->input('emotions');
        $entry->thinking_traps = $request->input('thinking_traps');
        $entry->balanced_thought = $request->input('balanced_thought')
        $entry->save();

        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }
```

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('thoughtjournal', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('entry_id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->date('entry_date');
            $table->mediumText('thought_entry');
            $table->
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: How are you expecting to store these 3 occurances into the db table, please dont say a comma delimited list

Comment: Also, if a check box is NOT checked, it is not sent to the PHP, so this `thinking_traps` array could be 0,1,2 or 3 occurances. You are not even treating it like an array yet

Comment: That's what I'm asking, how would they be added to the migration table and thus stored in the database?

Comment: Well you are designing the database, how do you want to store place these values on your database

Comment: I've just used them 3 occurrences as an example. I have many checkboxes but ideally I want the user to only be able to select up to 3 so there will be unchecked boxes as well

Comment: 3 separate columns would be best, one for each selection

Comment: If you have lots, maybe you should be considering another table

Comment: I think that would be a good idea yeah. Still I'm not sure how to store multiple values in the database like this, and only the ones that have been selected

Answer (score 1):

> I don't see that `thinking_traps` in your table migration file

## Model

```php
class ThoughtJournal{

   // Add it's type to casts as array
   public $casts = ['thinking_traps'=> 'array'];

   // Add it to fillables if you haven't
   public $fillable = ['thinking_traps',...];

   //...
}
```

## Storing

Second, in your storing method, when no item is selected in checkbox you need to set it as array, like so

```php
   ...
   $entry->thinking_traps     = $request->has('thinking_traps') 
                              ? $request->get('thinking_traps') 
                              : [];
```

And as a precaution, for the validation you can have it like so:

```php
$this->validate($request, [
   'thinking_traps' => 'nullable|in:1,2,3' // your values
]);
```

## Migrations

And for the migration i don't see that you have the column set there, you can modify your migration file like so:

```php
// You can have it as json
$table->json('thinking_traps')->nullable();

// or string
$table->string('thinking_traps')->nullable();
```

Or you can create a separate migration file if you don't want to recreate the table in shell/cmd through `artisan` like so:

```
php artisan make:migration add_thinking_traps_to_thoughtjournal_table --table=thoughtjournal
```

This command will add a migration file, separately, and in there add that column like how you normally would, you can then `php artisan migrate` to add that column.

Let us know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You should not store multiple values in a single row in your database. You should store it separately so your data are normalized.

Answer (score 0):

Post values will be an array even if you select one checkbox.

$thinking_traps = $request->input('thinking_traps');

$thinking_traps will be an array So try to save array values in separate table as multiple rows with foreign key